# My admob account ads are limited again and again from 7-8 months

Tags: admob, ads

I have a app on play store approx 1M downloads and daily new user is approx 2K and user engagement time is 1.5-2 min approx. but my admob account show me warning of limited ads in every 7-8 days and limited ads for approx 1 months means my ads running only for 7-8 days in 40-45 days of period.
And in this 7-8 day period, admib generate approx 3.5k impression over 12k requests. What can i do for n this case plz recommend me

Answer (score 0):

Shift to Applovin and add Admob as mediation partner and also integrate Facebook audience network as bidding.